Movie based on band and/or album with song about electrical? connection
Trying to remember what movie I saw this scene in. I know it was a movie connected with a band (Talking Heads comes to mind, but I don't think that's actually it).
The scene I can remember is one in a factory of some sort. All of the factory workers start singing, lead by a main male singer. The song has something to do with being connected to each other through electrical? (not sure if that's the word they use) connections which (I think) come from each other and the universe? Really odd scene and kind of random even in this movie from what I recall.

Hi. Do you remember the year\decade it was from? The country\language? The rest of the plot or other scenes? The actors or specific characters? (And was it live-action or animated? Was it in color?)

This is likely True Stories, which is a musical that resolves around the celebration of the Texas sesquicentennial. The celebration is sponsored by the Varicorp Corporation, a local computer manufacturing plant. One of the first people the Narrator (David Byrne) meets is Louis Fyne (John Goodman) a Country-Western-singing clean room technician at Varicorp.

Yes, it is TRUE STORIES. The song is called "Radiohead". I can't find that clip, but here is a different scene from the movie with the song. https://youtu.be/Zo8QoY7yLNs
